# How do I assign appropriate permissions on a Netatalk share?

Tags: centos, networking, permissions, apple

> How do I assign appropriate permissions on a Netatalk share?

I've ported an mdadm volume to a new machine.  It's mounted and working, there is a user set up called "design" which has access and can edit files predictably from within terminal.

Netatalk is all set up to enable our iMacs to use it for file-sharing and the drive is shared.   However this same user "design" when connecting from within Netatalk can view but not edit files.

My main admin user however, can read and write files fine from within a Netatalk share.

If I add "design" to the wheel group (sudoers group in Centos), it still has no access, and if I change the owner and group of some file being edited to "design", my admin account still has access in Netatalk but not the user design.

What does the admin account have, that the basic one does not?

There's a sentence about permissions here but it's greek to me: http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/3.1/htmldocs/afp.conf.5.html